# Geolocation Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation

I'm messing with the Google Maps API with Geolocation.  Everything is working as expected, however I keep getting this error in my console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined`

Here is my Geo Check:

```
// Does this browser support geolocation?
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize, locationError);
} else {
    showError("Your browser does not support Geolocation!");
}
```

My Success Handler:

```
function initialize(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;
    var acc = position.coords.accuracy;

    // Debugging
    console.log(position.coords);
    console.log("Accuracy: "+acc+"\nLatitude: "+lat+"\nLongitude: "+lon);

    // Google Maps API
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon),
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title:"Hello World!"
    });
}
```

I then initialize the map in my body tag `<body id="map" onload="initialize()">`

The map renders fine, everything is working as expected.  When I log `position.coords` to my console, I get a clean readout.  Why do I keep receiving this error?

Google and SO searches rendered no results...

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When document is loaded, the initialize method is called with no argument.
That's why you get the error.

Try this way instead:

```
function initCoords() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize, locationError);
  } else {
    showError("Your browser does not support Geolocation!");
  }
}
```

and in your html code:

`<body id="map" onload="initCoords()">`

Keep the `initialize` function as is.

Answer (score 1):

The error is probably here

```
<body id="map" onload="initialize()">
```

You're calling the initialize function with no parameters. Therefore the 'position' parameter is undefined

```
function initialize(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
```

Its as if you called

```
var lat = undefined.coords.latitude
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the error on google maps in cordova/phonegap on initialization before using the map object, make sure the google map html data-lat and data-long properties exist.

Here is a sample,

> <div class="widget uib_w_20 maps-size d-margins"
>   data-uib="media/google_maps" data-ver="0" data-rpath="null"
>   data-zoom="8" id="google-maps" data-center-auto="true"
>   data-lat="41.309697" data-long="-72.9370447">

without data-lat and data-long, and testing as web app, will fail during google map initialization